# Display mysql checkbox value in form

Tags: php

A simple question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a simple form that inserts the value 'on' to a database when a checkbox is checked

How do I get the checkbox checked when the data is pulled from the database when the form is revisited and displaying with the database information?

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
<input type="checkbox" name="positioning" class="input_margin" value="<? $row['positioning']; ?>">Positioning<br />
```

(I only need help with this, I have the sql query etc set up fine)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional statement to check the database value and echo 'checked' if it should be checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="positioning" class="input_margin" <? if($row['positioning']=='on'){echo 'checked';} ?>>
```

Comment: Perfect, had to make slight modification though, {echo 'checked="checked"';}

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `checked` property and not `value`.

The `value` field is what is provided if the box is checked (e.g `positioning=on`) for `value="on"`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="positioning" class="input_margin" <? if($row['positioning']) { ?> checked<? } ?>/>Positioning<br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Include the value attribute so the checkbox input will post "on" if checked.
Otherwise the form will initially retrieve a value but fail to post on any subsequent form submission. to the database

```
<input type="checkbox" name="positioning" class="input_margin" value="on" <? if($row['positioning'] =='on'){echo 'checked';} ?> />Positioning<br />
```